# Special character check with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input

i need if my value ( for example value = " Email " ) have @ character

```
web -> alert ( ' your message have been send ' )
```

else my value haven't @ character

```
web -> alert ( ' your email is wrong ')
```

so what would u guys suggest ?

Comment: there are tons of email validators available on web currently and seems you have not even used google to find a solution for this basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery Validation Plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

Use `type="email"` on your input.